# What is the CPU frequency driver for AMD?

Tags: drivers, cpu, cpu-frequency

I know we have acpi_cpufreq driver and intel_psteate driver to use.

However, I think intel_pstate driver is for Intel.

What's the CPU frequency driver for AMD?

Any introduction ( ex: governors ) for AMD CPU freq driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current AMD CPUs, the appropriate driver is [the ACPI driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/drivers/cpufreq/Kconfig.x86#L41). K6, K7, and K8 CPUs have specific drivers, but K10 and later are handled by the “generic” ACPI driver. There is additional support for [frequency sensitivity feedback](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/drivers/cpufreq/Kconfig.x86#L139) on Jaguar/Puma and later low-power CPUs, available in the `amd-freq-sensitivity` module.

The kernel contains [documentation on its CPU performance scaling](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/cpufreq.html) features.